# Is there a drop event for d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag-and-drop

Is it possible for me to implement the method of fetching the drag event setting data in the drop event.datatransfer like native javascript? Or is d3.js another way to do it? Any advice is helpful to me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of setting data in a drag event and getting it in a drop event.
And i wonder if d3.js has the same implementation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
      #drag{
        width: 100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color: aqua;
      }
      #drop{
        width: 100px;
        height:100px;
        background-color: darkgoldenrod;
      }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="drag" draggable="true">drag</div>
  <div id="drop">drop</div>
</body>
<script>
  var darg = document.getElementById('drag');
  var drop = document.getElementById('drop');


  darg.addEventListener('dragstart', function (e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', "someting");
  }, false);

  drop.addEventListener('dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  drop.addEventListener('drop', function (e) {
    console.log(e.dataTransfer.getData('text'));
  }, false);
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but ended up replicating the drop event by attaching a *mouseover* event on the target and validating a global state(`isDropped`) which is set to `true` on *dragend* and `false` on *dragstart*. Also reset `isDropped` to `false` inside *mouseover* at the end after you're done processing the drop action.

```js
let isDropped = false;
let targetElement = document.getElementByID('target');
let draggableElement = document.getElementByID('draggable');

targetElement.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    if(isDropped) {
        console.log('An item has been dropped');
        isDropped = false;
    }
});

draggableElement.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
    isDropped = false;
})

draggableElement.addEventListener('dragend', () => {
    isDropped = true;
})
```

Also also...ran into another issue where items render behind other elements so had to reorder HTML elements to deal with that since there's no straight forward z-Index for svg

Anyway hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can set the data on the reference object event,(by this._current) and then fetch it on the other related object event :

```
const clickElementEventHandler = function (event) {
this._current = event;

this._current.initPosition={
 x:d3.select(this).attr("x"),
 y:d3.select(this).attr("y")};
 d3.select(this).attr("fill", "black");

};
```

```js
var element = d3.select("#dargAbleRect");
var svg = d3.select("svg");

//append text to the svg
svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("font-size", 15)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("x", element.attr("x"))
  .attr("y", element.attr("y"))
  .text("drag me!");

// Event handlers
const clickElementEventHandler = function (event) {
  this._current = event;
  this._current.initPosition = {
    x: d3.select(this).attr("x"),
    y: d3.select(this).attr("y")
  };
  d3.select(this).attr("fill", "black");
};
const dragElementEventHandler = function (event) {
  d3.select(this).attr("x", event.x).attr("y", event.y);
  svg.select("text").text("dragging");
};
const dropElementEventHandler = function (event) {
  const { x, y } = this._current.initPosition;
  element.attr("fill", "red");
  svg.select("text").attr("x", x);
  svg.select("text").attr("y", y);
  svg.select("text").text(`I was here!! (X:${x},Y: ${y})` );
};

//bind Event Handlers to the element
element
  .attr("opacity", ".5")
  .call(
    d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", clickElementEventHandler)
      .on("drag", dragElementEventHandler)
      .on("end", dropElementEventHandler)
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.2/d3.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h3>Drop event for D3!!</h3>
      <svg width="400" height="400">
        <rect id="dargAbleRect" width="40px" height="40px" x="100" y="50" />
      </svg>
      <p></p>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The snippet is not working. I would edit to change it, but I have no idea what could I change. I suppose your answer is ok, just edit it so who comes later have a real proof that it is really working. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question but it looks to me like you need the "end" event on d3.drag().

https://github.com/d3/d3-drag

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that, but I want to trigger the drop event on the target element, not the 'end' event on the dragged element.

Comment: My approach would be to use x and y position of the 'end' event to detect which element you are dropping on?  If you do that, you can also add code to change the target element - ie fill, stroke etc..

Comment: Unless this is useful:  https://observablehq.com/@stwind/drag-and-drop

Comment: Or this.. https://bl.ocks.org/Lulkafe/097a34f373cfe70f3acec3f4c5c69f34

Comment: If you use x and y, you have to go through all the elements

Comment: The first link is implemented using native js events

Comment: So I think the answer is no, you can't trigger a drop event on the target element with d3.drag - you can only use the "end" and other drag functions to detect where you are dropping and trigger an event that way.

Comment: I agree with you.